# Issue with Push Notifications on React PWA - Works on Desktop but Not on Mobile

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a React Progressive Web Application (PWA) where I've successfully implemented push notifications. However, I am encountering an issue specifically on mobile devices, as the notifications are not appearing on my phone.

Here are the key details of my setup and the problem:

- **Working Environment**: Notifications function as expected on desktop browsers such as Safari and Chrome.
- **Mobile Environment:** The issue arises when attempting to trigger push notifications on mobile devices. The permission is granted at the mobile phone and I can access the notification's `body` but the message is not beeing displayed as a push message.
- **PWA Configuration:** I have ensured that my React app is correctly configured as a PWA, and the service worker is registered successfully, using Chrome's *Lighthouse*.
- **Browser Compatibility:** I have tested the application on multiple mobile browsers and apple simulator to ensure it's not a browser-specific problem.

Example of a button component:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Typography , Button, Box } from "@mui/material";

function NotificationTestComponent() {

    const [testError , setTestError] = useState(null);

    return ( 
            <Box sx={{padding: 2 , overflow: 'auto' , height: window.innerHeight}}>
                <Button onClick={() => {
                    Notification.requestPermission().then(perm => {
                        if(perm === 'granted'){
                            const notify = new Notification("First Notification" , {
                                body: "This is my first notification",
                                silent: false,
                            })
                            setTestError(notify.body);
                        }else{
                            setTestError(perm);
                        }
                    })
                }
                }>
                    Send Test Notification
                </Button>

                {
                    testError &&
                    <Typography>{testError}</Typography>
                }

            </Box>
    );
}

export default NotificationTestComponent;
```

On mobile, this component shows the `notify.body` as expected but without the push message.